# Silverlight Chart For Dummies

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts

I am just starting to learn Silverlight and I need to create a simple BarSeries chart. I am struggling because it's just not "clicking" yet. Can anyone post a complete xaml and .cs code for the most simple bar chart? I need to see (conceptually) how the data class 'hooks into' the xaml/view.

I've tried a number of links, examples and browsed the net ad nauseum, but to no avail. I just need to see something really really simple that I can play around with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem.
Copy this code to the MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new MainViewModel()
        {
            Items = new List<ItemViewModel>() { 
                new ItemViewModel { Title = "January", Value = 50 }, 
                new ItemViewModel { Title = "February", Value = 45 },
                new ItemViewModel { Title = "March", Value = 35 },
                new ItemViewModel { Title = "April", Value = 20 }
            }
        };

        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

And this code to the MainPage.xaml file:

```
<chart:Chart>
    <chart:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Title" />
</chart:Chart>
```